# Where can I get info about A. thaliana proteins' locations?

Tags: proteins, database

I have a list of *A. thaliana* proteins and I'd like to know their location in the cell. I've found [SUBA](https://suba.plantenergy.uwa.edu.au/) but they seem not to share their dataset and only allow queries through their website. It's inconvenient for me, because I need to locate 1.6k of proteins and process the results further. Is there a dataset or an API I could use instead?

PS. If this is not the right forum to ask this, please notify me.

Comment: cross-posted https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/18111/where-can-i-get-info-about-a-thaliana-proteins-locations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try using [The Arabidopsis Information Resource (TAIR)](https://www.arabidopsis.org/index.jsp).

It is the database specifically created for model higher plant *Arabidopsis thaliana*.

You can download the files in .fasta, .gz, .txt, .csv formats from their [DOWNLOAD WEBPAGE](https://www.arabidopsis.org/download/index.jsp). The website also provides links to other *A. thaliana* information resources.

PS:  The database is weekly updated.

**Edit 1:** [Try this](https://www.arabidopsis.org/download_files/Proteins/Properties/AtSubP_results) or track to *download_files/Proteins/Properties/AtSubP_results*

Comment: That's where I looked first but I haven't found any file with protein locations. In an [NCBI article](https://research-repository.uwa.edu.au/en/datasets/subcellular-localisation-database-for-arabidopsis-proteins-versio) about SUBA I've found a [link](https://research-repository.uwa.edu.au/en/datasets/subcellular-localisation-database-for-arabidopsis-proteins-versio) to some .csv files used by the website, although they have to be cleaned to be usable.

Comment: can you point to where on TAIR specifically these localisome data reside?

Comment: @micoay, I have added a link to my answer. Please let me know if it works for you. I'm assuming you already have the protein-ID list.

Comment: Thanks, I missed this file. For people searching for the file on the website: Downloads/Proteins/Properties/AtSubP_results.

Comment: @micoay, If that has solved your problem, then please accept my answer by clicking a tick button on the left side of my answer on your forum. I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

If you click through to the [actual SUBA4 publication](https://academic.oup.com/nar/article/45/D1/D1064/2572064#51199052), you can see in the data availability section that they have reposited source datasets from which their predictions are derived, at http://dx.doi.org/10.4225/23/581055ddcb1ce.

These appear to be standard e.g. CSV files of various data layers, such as [here](https://research-repository.uwa.edu.au/files/13409933/SUBA4_summary.csv). It may take some effort (e.g. their algorithm) to integrate these data sources, I am not familiar with these datasets.

It is of course inconvenient that they don't choose to advertise this on the server itself.

Comment: Thanks, I found it too, after posting here. I was hoping there was a link on their website I missed.